# Switch/case statement

Tags: regex, powershell, switch-statement

I have a function called `tabLength` that *should* return a string.  This is for formatting in a text document.

Could anyone check out my switch statement and see why I am getting an error on line 6.  That is the 'case' that the switch statement is going through.

```
Function tabLength ( $line ) {
    $lineLength = $line.Length

    switch -regex ( $lineLength ) {
        "[1-4]" { return "`t`t`t" }
        "[5-15]" { return "`t`t" }
        "[16-24]" { return "`t" }
        default { return "`t" }
    }
}
```

Error Message:

```
Invalid regular expression pattern: [5-15].
At C:\Users\name\desktop\nslookup.ps1:52 char:11
+         "[5-15]" <<<<  { return "" }
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ([5-15]:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegularExpression
```

It is only happening to values being sent through `[5-15]`.

Comment: Could you post the exact error message? Works perfectly fine here (PS 4.0 on Win7).

Comment: Yeah sorry about that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[5-15]` is not a valid regex character class. You are matching strings, not numbers, so `[5-15]` essentially says "match a single character from '5' through '1', or '5'" which is not what you want.

If you remove that middle condition, the `[16-24]` should fail similarly.

Try a `switch` statement that doesn't use regex, but uses a script block for conditions so you can use a range to test, like this:

```psh
Function tabLength ( $line ) {
    $lineLength = $line.Length

    switch ( $lineLength ) {
        { 1..4 -contains $_ } { return "`t`t`t" }
        { 5..15 -contains $_ } { return "`t`t" }
        { 16..24 -contains $_ } { return "`t" }
        default { return "`t" }
    }
}
```

In powershell 3+, you could use the `-in` operator and reverse the order:

```psh
Function tabLength ( $line ) {
    $lineLength = $line.Length

    switch ( $lineLength ) {
        { $_ -in  1..4 } { return "`t`t`t" }
        { $_ -in 5..15 } { return "`t`t" }
        { $_ -in 16..24 } { return "`t" }
        default { return "`t" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Another case where Regex simply isn't worth it. I'll show myself out

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen well this is homework after all, sometimes the bounds of the problems given don't make sense, so maybe he *must* use regex for this, so +1 for showing the regex way.

Answer (score 4):

[@briantist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31686311/1630171) beat me to answering your immediate question. However, since you say your goal is to format text, you may want to consider an entirely different approach.

PowerShell has a [format operator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kathykam/archive/2006/03/29/564426.aspx) (`-f`) that allows you to format strings (as well as numbers or dates) in various ways. For instance if you want text aligned to the right of a 30 character wide column (i.e. left-padded text), you could do something like this:

```
Function alignRight ( $line ) {
    '{0,30}' -f $line
}
```

You could also use this for a column that's padded on the right.

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> '-{0,5}-' -f 'abc'
-  abc-
PS C:\> '-{0,-5}-' -f 'abc'
-abc  -
```

Comment: Great job getting to what is (probably) the actual root problem!

Answer (score 2):

Regex match character-by-character, not integers. The range `[5-15]` simply doesn't make sense for the regex engines.

Try adding anchors:

```
Function tabLength ( $line ) {
    $lineLength = $line.Length

    switch -regex ( $lineLength ) {
        "^[1-4]$" { return "`t`t`t" }
        "^[5-9]$|^1[0-5]$" { return "`t`t" }
        "^1[6-9]$|^2[0-4]$" { return "`t" }
        default { return "`t" }
    }
}
```